# How to place 3 continuous row in to the 3 stacked row in single access report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-reports

I have multiple employee's salary data in tabular format for different months as displayed in the 3rd and 2nd image. (Presently extracted for a single employee in the following images example). There are 35 salary fields/columns for each employee and salary heads are different for different type of job profile. 3rd and 2nd images represent salary data table for all job profile employee. Because the table has many columns so I posted only two part of a single table in third and second images. There are also other fields which have 0 values or more than 0 as per the employee's job profile. I created a query to extract quarterly data for a single employee from the table as per the third and second images.

The first image is the result, which I want to arrange as the stacked format. Presently my report showing only single month data in the this report. There is report load event code to show only heads which have values more than 0 as following:

```
Dim C As Control

For Each C In Me.Report

If TypeOf C Is TextBox Then

        If IsNull(C) Or C = "" Or C = 0 Or C = "0" Then
            C.Visible = False
            C.Height = 0
        Else
            C.Visible = True
        End If
End If
```

I want to display the result as per the report images as follows. Is it possible to place 3 stacked column? thanks for the help and any suggestions.

Example images:

[image: rptQuerterlyITStatement]

[image: qryPayRollData]

[image: qryPayRollData1]

Comment: The example that you tried to provide is not accessible.

Comment: igorM.. Example link working

Comment: So what is the actual question?  Is the only problem getting the data in quarterly groups?  The images are not very useful, because the column names are very cryptic and the columns do not include any date values.  The question indicates that the "Second image" has something to do with printing quarterly data on a single page, but it only has a bunch of zero values... seems to me completely useless.  Finally, it is expected on Stackoverflow to show what you have tried and why it is not working.  Do not just post requirements and ask for a solution.

Comment: C perkins, i edited my question to clear my query.  Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: @user2245124  If you want to notify a certain user of a comment, type `@` followed by the username... just as I did for your username.  Otherwise they may never know that you responded.  Click on the help link next to the comment box for more info.

Comment: It is all still too confusing. You say that the 2nd & 3rd images are quarterly data (?), but you do not explain your data sufficiently.  Does the `PayBill` column indicate the quarterly month?  (If so, why are they not evenly spaced and where is the first quarter row?  Next, **you mention code in the load event** but don't show that code. You also mention **pasting salary heads**, but it's not clear what that means.  Are you actually copy and pasting data into the report design?  The data is almost identical in the different rows, so it is very difficult to differentiate data in example rows.

Comment: You should include the report's RecordSource property query.  If there is another query which shows the quarterly data, then show that query also.  And for both of those, I do not mean more images.  You need to share the SQL text for those queries.

Comment: @CPerkins Both 2nd & 3rd images are part of a single query and I posted both to understand about various salary heads/columns or fields of the database query. There are also various salary heads/columns or fields in this query ahead.

Comment: @CPerkins I used following report OnLoad event code:                               
  Private Sub Report_Load()
  Dim C As Control

For Each C In Me.Report

    If TypeOf C Is TextBox Then
        
            If IsNull(C) Or C = "" Or C = 0 Or C = "0" Then
                C.Visible = False
                C.Height = 0
            Else
                C.Visible = True
            End If
    End If
Next C

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the following SQL query to a salary per employee per quarter considering that your table contains only one-year salaries

```
 SELECT
        EmployeeName
        ,SUM(IIF(Month([DateColumn]) BETWEEN 1 AND 3, Salary, 0)) AS Salary_Q1
        ,SUM(IIF(Month([DateColumn]) BETWEEN 4 AND 6, Salary, 0)) AS Salary_Q2
        ,SUM(IIF(Month([DateColumn]) BETWEEN 7 AND 9, Salary, 0)) AS Salary_Q3
        ,SUM(IIF(Month([DateColumn]) BETWEEN 10 AND 12, Salary, 0)) AS Salary_Q4
FROM TblSalary
GROUP BY EmployeeName
```

Comment: MS Access does not have `CASE WHEN`, you'll need to use `SWITCH` or `IIF`.

Comment: You could also use `iif(datepart("q", datecolumn)=1, Salary, 0)` etc. as an alternative.

Comment: @igorM... I think, you could not understand my issue.. i can group query but issue is to put up 3 months row fields to three columns in single report.. each report for each employee.. see images

Comment: @user2245124 the easiest way to pull out the months is usually a crosstab query. get everything else done then make the bottom of the report a sub report and bind to a crosstab query.  There are lots of tutorials online under crosstab and access

Comment: @mazoula there are lots of value fields to show in report and crosstab can show only single value field.. so any alternate suggestion pls

Comment: @user2245124 since there is no standard table design, that I know of, that has multiple values in a cell.  perhaps refine your plan to multiple crosstabs/report sections.  You could try concatenating several value fields together using the string data type and see if that is user friendly.

Comment: How can I retrieve data in the second and third column for next months data in a stacked format which is shown in the above first image (report). Presently it retrive only first month data in all three column. Any help from this platform!